# Jquery Function should repeat everytime a click the trigger (but it doesnt)

Tags: jquery, css, function, html

Well, I have this beautifull little site wich has a div that `overflows:hidden` the content that doesnt fit the wrapper. I want to `margin-top: $value-120px` everytime i click a span `class'd .maisfilme`. This is what i got

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
$(".maisfilme").on("click", function() {
     var $mtop = $(this).css('margin-top');

        var $vai = (parseInt($mtop)+ 110 + "px");
    $("#filme").css ({
        'margin-top' : "-"+$vai
    });
});
});
```

It actually does the job. It gets margin-top, increases its int value +120px, put a - before it and so, slides the div up.
The real problem is that it only happens ONCE. If I click `.maisfilme` once more, nothing happens.
Could someone know what should I do so the function acts everytime `.maisfilme` is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second time you do it it's going to be -(-110 + 110) which isn't increasing the magnitude like you want.  You need to change the logic of your sign if you want it to go more negative each time.

In addition you are fetching the css from `$(this)`, but setting it on `$("#filme")` so it won't go up each time unless those happen to be the same object.  Those need to be the same for it to accumulate each time you click.

To make it go more negative each time, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".maisfilme").on("click", function() {
        var $mtop = $(this).css('margin-top');

        var $vai = (parseInt($mtop) - 110) + "px";
        $(this).css ({
            'margin-top' : $vai
        });
    });
});
```

or a slightly different version which gives a slightly different result if the initial value of the margin-top is not zero (more like what your first iteration does):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".maisfilme").on("click", function() {
        var $mtop = $(this).css('margin-top');

        var $vai = (-(Math.abs(parseInt($mtop)) + 110)) + "px";
        $(this).css ({
            'margin-top' : $vai
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well,thanks for that, but unfortunally it only works the first time i click ;( if I click .maisfilme again, nothing happens

Comment: @user1576978 - You'll have to give us a working copy of the HTML/CSS for us to help further.  You've only given us a piece of the picture.

Comment: You can see it live here -> http://www.matheusduarte.com/site/ it is on box2 "Producao Musical", the one with the film

Comment: @user1576978 - Actually, the main problem is that you are getting the CSS from `$(this)`, but setting it on `$("#filme")` so unless those are the same object, your CSS won't accumulate each time.  You need to change one of those to match the other.

Comment: the .maisfilme is kindda invisible... lol. it is on "⇓ Prox", beside the blonde girl's t

Comment: THANK YOU!All i had to do was change var $mtop = $(this).css('margin-top'); to var $mtop = $("#filme").css('margin-top'); worked fine!!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: i mean... REALLY THANKS A LOT, it meant a lot to me, your help saved my sleep hours tonight. 3:30am here bye