# How to rotate always clockwise using css and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I have a refresh button, and i want it to rotate slowly when clicked. So i think of using `transition` and `transform`, here is what i implemented:

```
#refresh{
  transition:all 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s;
}
#refresh.rotate{
  transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

$("#refresh").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
})
```

In this way, when i click for the first time, it rotates clockwise, but for the second time, it rotates anti-clockwise, since it comes back to the beginning.

So I change the code to :

```
$("#refresh").on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(360deg)');
});
```

In this time, for the second time and latter, nothing happens when i click, since it already at 360 degree position.

How to make the refresh button rotate clockwise for every time I click it?

**Edit**: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn4095vo/)

Comment: Can we se a demo? It would be easier to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` as a CSS style to make it animate forever.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814295/jquery-function-should-repeat-everytime-a-click-the-trigger-but-it-doesnt): keeping a running total of how far it's rotated and setting `transform: rotate(**the accumulated value**deg)` in the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
$("#refresh").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('rotate').promise().done(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('rotate');   
   });;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something using a mix of Jquery and CSS3 animations as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        a = a +5;
        $('.this-rotates').css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+a+'deg)');
        $('.this-rotates').css('-moz-transform','rotate('+a+'deg)');
        $('.this-rotates').css('transform','rotate('+a+'deg)');
    },50);
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/q4u8a64f/2/